# rails console error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-console

I'm trying to user rails console but every time I type a command I get

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for main:Object
    from (irb):3
    from /Users/Home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /Users/Home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/Home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I couldn't view any of my models or even perform basic things

Could anyone please give any suggestion?

Many Thanks
Ans

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

user = User.new(//constructor parameters)

or

user = User.create(//constructor parameters)

or

user = User.new() 
//blank user object

the second method will create and save your record.